# How to call onPaymentAuthorized both success and error states in Google pay react button?

Tags: reactjs, google-pay

I am implementing google pay react button and wants to implement onPaymentAuthorized success and error. But at a time I can only use Success state or Error state. Is there any way to use both of them? is this function used when user enter invalid card or card that has insufficient amount? Please help me to figure it out. Here is my code

```
<GooglePayButton
                                environment="TEST"
                                paymentRequest={{
                                    apiVersion: 2,
                                    apiVersionMinor: 0,
                                    allowedPaymentMethods: [
                                    {
                                        type: 'CARD',
                                        parameters: {
                                        allowedAuthMethods: ['PAN_ONLY', 'CRYPTOGRAM_3DS'],
                                        allowedCardNetworks: ['MASTERCARD', 'VISA'],
                                        },
                                        tokenizationSpecification: {
                                        type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
                                        parameters: {
                                            gateway: "moneris",
                                            gatewayMerchantId: "monca05217"
                                        },
                                        },
                                    },
                                    ],
                                    merchantInfo: {
                                    merchantId: '12345678901234567890',
                                    merchantName: 'Demo Merchant',
                                    },
                                    transactionInfo: {
                                    totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
                                    totalPriceLabel: 'Total',
                                    totalPrice: '50.00',
                                    currencyCode: 'USD',
                                    countryCode: 'US',
                                    },
                                    callbackIntents: ['PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION'],
                                    emailRequired: true,
                                }}
                                onLoadPaymentData={paymentRequest => {
                                    console.log('load payment data', paymentRequest);
                                    props.cardDetail(paymentRequest,endDate);                                        
                                }} 
                                onPaymentAuthorized={() => ({ transactionState: 'SUCCESS' })}                                   
                                />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you might use `onPaymentAuthorized` to implement a check for sufficient funds: https://jsfiddle.net/hz3e7pyw/

```
<GooglePayButton
  environment="TEST"
  paymentRequest={paymentRequest}
  onLoadPaymentData={handleLoadPaymentData}
  onPaymentAuthorized={async () => {
    if (await hasSufficientFunds()) {
      return { transactionState: 'SUCCESS' }; 
    } else {
      return {
        transactionState: 'ERROR', 
        error: {
          reason: "PAYMENT_DATA_INVALID",
          message: "Insufficient funds (shouldSucceed is false), click Pay again.",
          intent: "PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION"
        }
      }; 
    }
  }}
  />
```

You would implement your own `hasSufficientFunds` method and return the appropriate error with message.

See also: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/response-objects#PaymentAuthorizationResult